# Spring GlobalExceptionHandler : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve parameter [0] ... No suitable resolver

Tags: spring

I had the following error when trying to setup a global exception handler to respond with a generic error response:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException::class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    fun handleClientException(exception: HttpClientErrorException): ErrorDto {
        // do something with client errors, like logging
        return ErrorDto(errorMessage)
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception::class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    fun handleServerException(exception: HttpClientErrorException): ErrorDto {
        // do some other thing with server errors, like alerts
        return ErrorDto(errorMessage)
    }

}

data class ErrorDto(val message: String)

@RestController
class DemoController {
    @GetMapping("/error")
    @ResponseBody
    fun error(): ErrorDto {
        throw RuntimeException("test")
    }
}
```

and the error:

```
ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Failure in @ExceptionHandler
public ErrorDto
GlobalExceptionHandler.handleServerException(org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException)

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve parameter [0] in
public ErrorDto
GlobalExceptionHandler.handleServerException(org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException):
No suitable resolver    at
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:163)
    at
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at
(...)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is not a duplicate of [spring mvc controller error java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable resolver for argument [0]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329365/spring-mvc-controller-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-suitable-resolve) which was an Hibernate issue. I am not using Hibernate here.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone arriving from Google, I had this issue and traced it to a second exception being thrown within my "handler" method. The `Failure in @ExceptionHandler` occurs when the handler catches an error, then within the method a _different_ exception gets thrown

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my case, this was a copy-paste error.

I was throwing a `RuntimeException` but I configured the exception handler to support `HttpClientErrorException` :

`fun handleServerException(exception: HttpClientErrorException)`

In this case, the fix is to use the same Exception class in the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation as in the method parameter:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception::class) // <-- must match method parameter
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
fun handleServerException(exception: Exception): ErrorDto { // <-- fix here
    // do some other thing with server errors, like alerts
    return ErrorDto(errorMessage)
}
```

Comment: Congrats with 3K

Comment: This just happened to me as well, also make sure you import the correct `ServerHttpRequest`class. In my case I was importing `org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest`when it should be `org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest`. Notice it is in the **reactive** package. This has to do with your project using `spring-boot-starter-web` or `spring-boot-starter-webflux`